# How to get nautilus to show file previews thumbnails for office files?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, nautilus, thumbnails

LibreOffice files have thumbnails, Microsoft Office files don't. Sometimes I get sent Microsoft Office files and they come with a thumbnail but as soon as I save the file in LibreOffice, nautilus stops showing a thumbnail for it.

I'm using UbuntuGnome 16.04 in case it matters.

Answer (score 5):

Following the steps in [this article by Nicolas Bernaerts](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/325-gnome-shell-generate-msoffice-thumbnail-nautilus) might help.

It explains how to configure Nautilus (or PCManFM) to display appropriate thumbnail icons (with a preview of the first page and the document type indicated) for Microsoft Office documents. It uses the LibreOffice CLI document type conversion tool [`unoconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/unoconv.1.html).

> This procedure has been tested under Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS with Libre Office 4.2 & 5.0. It should be applicable to many Gnome based distributions. It has also been tested under Lubuntu 14.04 LTS with PCManFM.

The article provides a script, which Nautilus can use as its thumbnailer for MS Office files.

### The easy way

Install the thumbnailer, its icons, and the Nautilus configuration file telling it to use this thumbnailer for MS Office mimetypes from [the author's GitHub repository](https://github.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/tree/master/thumbnailer/msoffice) using these commands:

```bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/master/thumbnailer/msoffice/msoffice-thumbnailer-install.sh
chmod +x msoffice-thumbnailer-install.sh
./msoffice-thumbnailer-install.sh
```

the script contains `sudo`, so it's going to ask for your password.

#### Then delete cached thumbnails

**If you use Nautilus**

```bash
rm -r $HOME/.cache/thumbnails
nautilus -q
```

**If using Lubuntu/PCManFM**, run:

```bash
rm -r $HOME/.thumbnails
```

And icons will be fixed after reboot.

### For manual installation

- Save the thumbnailer script as `/usr/local/sbin/lo-thumbnailer`
- Download the icons from the [author's GitHub repository](https://github.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/tree/master/thumbnailer/msoffice/icons) and save them in `/usr/local/sbin/msoffice-thumbnailer-icons`.
- Save instructions for Nautilus to use the script as thumbnailer as `/usr/share/thumbnailers/msoffice.thumbnailer`. The file should contain:

```
    [Thumbnailer Entry]
    TryExec=/usr/local/sbin/msoffice-thumbnailer
    Exec=/usr/local/sbin/msoffice-thumbnailer %u %o %s
    MimeType=application/msword;application/vnd.ms-word;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;application/vnd.ms-excel;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template;application/vnd.ms-powerpoint;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow;application/ms-office;
```

- Finally, delete cached thumbnails as explained in **The easy way** above.